# CSS Fixed Fluid Columns with no extra markup?

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm looking for a way to create a CSS layout where the left column is fluid and the right column is fixed using the exact markup below.  I don't think it is possible. Am I wrong?

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Fluid Column</div>
  <div class="right">Fixed Column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will need the fixed column to be first in your markup, because it will be using the float property. For the fluid column you then set a margin so the 2 columns do not overlap. Is it possible to swap the order of the 2 containers for you?

Comment: No. The order must remain as is because I plan on using media queries to display this in a mobile layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper { width: 900px; }
#left { float: left; width: 100%; margin: 0 -100px 0 0 ; }
#content { margin: 0 100px 0 0; }
#right { float: right; width: 100px; }
```

***Note:** Remove `wrapper` if you want the width to be 100%.*

Comment: Thanks. But I am trying to do this without the nested DIV in the order given. Not sure it is possible though.

Comment: I went with this solutions because it was the most stable.  I just couldn't find a way to do it with only 3 divs.

Comment: Adding extra markup isn't necessarily a bad thing. Glad to hear you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
* { padding:0px; margin:0px; }

.wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.left {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left:0; right:150px;
    background-color:#999999;
}
.right {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    right:0; 
    width:150px;
    background-color:#AAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: Looking closer this is really close, but according to [PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) it doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: @Adam Youngers - I modified my answer.  Let me know if that's not it.  You have the option of using min-width if you want for the fluid column.  Also, the columns don't have to size their height together this way, either.  You could take out "bottom:0;" and set a height value or use auto to size to the contents.

Comment: Very close. One issue though is that it seems the bottom:0; is based of the screen size and not the height of the document?  [See Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cbp3K/8/)

Comment: @Adam Youngers - Sorry, I've run out of ideas unless you want to manually set the height of the wrapper or just not use a container.  I'm thinking it's just not possible without display:table or without nesting the left column in one more div.  According to the site you gave, display:table-cell works in Safari 5, 4 and even 3 just not without display:table-row.  You could probably put display:table on the body (although it's not usually something people like to do, it might work) IE<8 is a problem though, if you care about them.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I'm going to go with the nested div approach for now. It's not optimal, but it is well supported.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a viable solution at this point in time but if you are not adverse to using bleeding-edge CSS you could also use the CSS3 [flex box module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/).  Using vendor specific prefixes, it is currently supported in Firefox, and Webkit based browsers such as Safari and Google Chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
    .wrapper {
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: flexbox;
        -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        flex-direction: lr; /* box-orient has been renamed in the most recent version of the draft */
        width: 100%;
    }
    .right {
            width:150px;
            background-color: #eee;
    }
    .left {
            -moz-box-flex: 1;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            flex-box: 1; /* box-flex has been renamed flex-box */
    }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Fluid Column</div>
  <div class="right">Fixed Column</div>
</div>
```

For the sake of semantics, you might want to rename *.left* and *.right* to something like *.content* and *.sidebar*

Comment: I can't wait for this to be more fully supported.  I'd like to try this paired with Modernizer and Richard Herrera's Flexie polyfill, but it's a bit to bleeding-edge for the project I am working on.